# Why is the prediction not being displayed on browser?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to predict pneumonia using a trained model that I have. I am using Flask for this. The error I am receiving is

The file "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\CAD\PROJECTS\m3cad\predict" cannot be found. It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.

Following are the index.html and detect.py code:

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image Prediction</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Image Prediction</h1>
    <form action="/predict" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
        <label for="image-file">Select an image file:</label>
        <input type="file" name="image-file" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Make Prediction" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**DETECT.PY**

```
from flask import Flask, request
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from tensorflow.keras.utils import img_to_array
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import load_model

# Load the model
model = load_model('model12.h5')

# Create a Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Route for handling the file input
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
  # Read the image file
  image_file = request.files['image-file']
  image_data = image_file.read()
  image = mpimg.imread(image_data)

  # Preprocess the image
  test_image = img_to_array(image)
  test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)

  # Make a prediction
  pred = model.predict(test_image)
  predict = np.argmax(pred, axis=-1)

  # Display the prediction result
  if predict == 0:
    prediction = 'Normal'
  else:
    prediction = 'Pneumonia +VE'

  plt.imshow(image)
  plt.suptitle(prediction, fontsize=20)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()

# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

Comment: Run your server on localhost on port 8080. Then open your index.html file through localhost, like `localhost:8080/index.html`. Then it may work.

Comment: I don't understand where your error is coming from, but regardless, even when you fix that problem you're showing the plot on the server not the client. It sort of looks like you're trying to reinvent something like JupyterLab or Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Error comes from here <form action="/predict" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> in html file

Answer (score 0):

when you run `Detect.py` in the console, there should be the address where your server is running, something like: `localhost:5000`

put this in your browser and navigate to `/predict`

If it is not showing up try to change:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=true)
```

Comment: Can you include the changes in my above code?